# Android JSON dosn't display data into list view

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-layout

I'm newbie in android programming, and going crazy with my problem.. I have readed about ~30 tutorials **How to display JSON data into Android**, but can't fix code, so it work. (At this moment, I don't get any errors. And my JSON file is working.

So you don't ask, why I'm using ImageButtons - It's because (when I get this working), I want to display clickable images for each post(Like upvote button, downvote button and more).

I have looked in many tutorials and stackoverflow questions, but in each page code are really different and this was most simpliest of all.

FunActivity(MainActivity).java

```
package crelix.carparadise;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FunActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> postList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    getJSON("http://10.10.7.6/Android/Pages/Fun.php");
}


private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            try {
                loadIntoListView(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
    getJSON.execute();
}

private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject posts = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = posts.getString("id");
        String title = posts.getString("title");
        String image = posts.getString("image");
        String upvotes = posts.getString("upvotes");
        String downvotes = posts.getString("downvotes");
        String comments = posts.getString("comments");
        String share = posts.getString("share");
        String report = posts.getString("report");
        String date = posts.getString("date");
        String addedby = posts.getString("addedby");


        // tmp hash map for single contact
        HashMap<String, String> post = new HashMap<>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        post.put("id", id);
        post.put("title", title);
        post.put("image", image);
        post.put("upvotes", upvotes);
        post.put("downvotes", downvotes);
        post.put("comments", comments);
        post.put("share", share);
        post.put("report", report);
        post.put("date", date);
        post.put("addedby", addedby);

        // adding contact to contact list
        postList.add(post);
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FunActivity.this, postList,
            R.layout.fun_posts, new String[]{ "title","image","upvotes","downvotes","comments","share","report","date","addedby"},
            new int[]{R.id.titleTv, R.id.imageBtn, R.id.upvoteBtn, R.id.downvoteBtn, R.id.commentBtn, R.id.shareBtn, R.id.reportBtn, R.id.date, R.id.addedbyBtn});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

fun_posts(list_item).xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/upvoteBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/downvoteBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/commentBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/reportBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/addedbyBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And activity_fun.xml(Main layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="crelix.carparadise.FunActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</ListView>
```

Comment: the way you are consuming the API is wrong. Also async task

Comment: Use recyclerview instead of listview

Comment: this is good example https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: @Ankur_009 I have seen this too. But I wanted to get simple code, that can be used only in one file. Becouse I got large php project with more than 20 databases, many data and more. If I will make this much files for each, it will be crazy..

Comment: but that provide code readability and flexibility to change.

Comment: you dont need a hashmap. you can use a model. Create a model with setters and getters. and set the strings using the model. then add each iteration of the json into that arraylist. list.add(newPost(id, title, image.....). then create a custom listview and set the textview from that arraylist. simple.